# If autoload isn't loaded until later, how does my index.php file know how to use classes?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am working on a Symfony app. The app's index.php file contains the following logic:

```
<?php

use App\Kernel;
use Sonata\PageBundle\Request\RequestFactory;
use Sonata\PageBundle\Request\SiteRequest as Request;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

require dirname(__DIR__).'/config/bootstrap.php';

if ($_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']) {
    umask(0000);

    Debug::enable();
}

...
```

The `bootstrap.php` file, in turn, contains this logic:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv;

require dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload.php';

...
```

My understanding of `use` statements is that they only work if there is some sort of autoloading going on. So how are these `use` statements working before the autoloader is included?

Comment: No, you can add `use` statements of unexisting classes and it won't throw any error. Autoloading is triggered when really using the classes.

Comment: Thanks, AymDev. That answers my question.